# Pair and Connecting to Bluetooth Classic Speaker iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, speaker

I realise most of the searches are quite old on this topic and not after Core Bluetooth now supports more than just BLE connections (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901?time=556).
Simply by running the RxBluetoothKit example app I am able to discover my speaker and inspect its services. However I am unsure how to actually get the speaker to pair with the phone, after a while the speaker disconnects. I am struggling to get information on the protocol and/or how to proceed.

Or is this still not possible: "And so if you're calling connect on a BR/EDR device, if your app is in foreground, then we'll try to make a connection out to that device for you." - it seems like querying and communication with an already paired device is what they were getting at in the talk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The user needs to complete the initial discovery and pairing operation through the settings app

Comment: So it isn't possible to initiate pairing through the app (albeit of a previously paired device)?

Comment: If it is previously paired then you don't need to pair.

Comment: However calling connect() and reading characteristics doesn't cause the speaker to show up on control centre as connected so I assumed there was a small distinction between connect and the control centre connect - I understand that the initially pairing process is distinct.

Comment: Calling `connect` will only connect you to the BR/EDR gatt service. iOS should handle the audio profile connection for you if the devices are paired

Comment: I'm using the "BT Inspector" app from the app store and it can create BLE and classic connections to a pair of headphones, from what I can see (the headphones are paired when I check back to Settings after using the app). The Bose app seems to be able to do the same, without visiting the iOS Settings app.